# Joining 3 tables in mysql where data does not live in both joins

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I am having an issue joining 3 tables where the data i need is one of two tables, but not both.

So lets say we have table 'customers' with columns 'id', 'city', 'state', and 2 data tables data_a and data_b with column 'id' and the data i want.

right now i have a statement similar to the below.

```
SELECT cust.id, cust.city, cust.state, a.info as infoa, b.info as infob
  FROM customers cust
  INNER JOIN data_a a 
    ON cust.id = a.id
  INNER JOIN data_b b
    ON cust.id = b.id
  WHERE cust.city = 'mytown';
```

This takes forever to run, and I have not gotten any responses from the query since i will kill it before it finishes (if it will ever actually finish).

If I remove the second data table the statement works fine, only when I added it do i run into issues. All the id columns are indexed, as well as the city column.

Or am I better off creating a temp table and doing 2 joins, inserting those into the temp and reading from the temp?

edit: fixed the typo

If i do left joins the query sits at executing, presumably indefinitely. When using Inner Joins I will get a empty set.

Comment: Not sure if this will solve anything but what happens if you use `left join`s. That always seems to work for me with a similar select.

Comment: You're joining twice with the same data with the `ON cust.id = b.id` that's tripping you

Comment: Typo? You're joining on `b.id` in BOTH joins. If that's in your real query, then there's your problem.

Comment: Are the id field PK? Are the tables indexed?

Comment: @Nico all 3 tables are indexed on id and city, no Primary Key exists however

Comment: How many rows do you expect to get joined to a `customer` from `data_a` and `data_b`? `data_a` and `data_b` seems to be independent of each other -> you are practically `CROSS JOIN`ing them per `customer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the join will be on one table, but not both, then you need LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT cust.id, cust.city, cust.state, a.info as infoa, b.info as infob
  FROM customers cust
  LEFT JOIN data_a a 
    ON a.id = cust.id
  LEFT JOIN data_b b
    ON b.id = cust.id
  WHERE cust.city = 'mytown';
```

Ensure that you have the following indexes:

```
cust: ('city')
data_a: ('id')
data_b: ('id')
```

Comment: This worked, just took a minute to respond. I'm positive I tried this already but ill go with it and try to get it moving faster.

Comment: @NickR, to get it faster create primary keys on `data_a.id` and `data_b.id` and `cust.id` and to go the whole hog a unique index on `cust.city, cust.id`...